# Setting the options from the list selected using JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, drop-down-menu

I have a `<select></select>` now the list contains some option like `a, b, and c` now i want that when user enters `a` in `textbox` and click button `a` should be selected in select list, and henceforth, can anyone help me to achieve this in **JQuery**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that this is your `select`:

```
<select>
    <option id="a" value="a"/>
    <option id="b" value="b"/>
    <option id="c" value="c"/>
    <option id="d" value="d"/>
</select>
```

And this is you `input`

```
<input type="text" id="textbox" /> <input type="button" id="button"/>
```

And this is your `script`

```
<script>
    $('#button').click(new function(){
        var option = $("#textbox").val();
        $('select #'+option).attr("selected='true'"); 
    });
</script>
```

Will this work?

Answer (score 2):

For a markup like below,

```
<select id="selectOpt">
   <option value="a">a</option>
   <option value="b">b</option>
   <option value="c">c</option>
</select>

<input type="textbox" id="txtbox1" />

<button id="sch">Select</button>
```

Below script should do the trick,

```
$('#sch').on('click', function () {      //<-Bind click handler for button using .on
     var txtVal = $('#txtbox1').val();   //<-Get the value entered in the textbox

     if ($('#selectOpt option[value=' + txtVal + ']').length > 0) {
        //^-- Above line checks if the entered value exist in the options list

        $('#selectOpt').val(txtVal );    //<-Set the value of the select with the entered value
     }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/UNmT8/1/)

Comment: You should probably throw in a check to make sure the option exists. Though it may make no difference.

Comment: @DavidThomas Yup, the question is not complete.. so i was throwing a rough version.

Comment: I know; but so long as you attempted to answer... =b

Comment: @DavidThomas Updated with a demo :)

Comment: And up-voted! Seriously, though, thanks for improving the answer. =)

Answer (score 2):

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
  $("#someButton").click(function(){
    $("#someSelect").val($("#someInput").val());
  });
});
```

Html:

```
<select id="someSelect">
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
</select>
<input id="someInput" type="text" />
<button id="someButton">Go</button>
```

See a working example here: http://jsbin.com/ipevaz/3/edit

Comment: You'll be setting the value of *all* selects with the value of the first of *all* the `input` elements, after clicking on *any* button with that code.

Comment: I know this. If he doesn't understand that, then he probably shouldn't be using jquery at all.

Comment: Looking at the question, do you think s/he understands jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

```
<select>
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">d</option>
  <option value="c">c</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="letext" maxlength="1"/>
<input type="button" id="select" value="Select" />
​


$('#select').click(function(){

    $('select option[value=' +  $('#letext').val() +']').prop('selected','true')
    });​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chepe263/UNmT8/

the button function is find a option with the value equal to the input

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following HTML to accomplish this.

```
<input type="text" id="input" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Move to Select" />

<select>
    <option value="a">a</option>      
    <option value="b">b</option>      
    <option value="c">c</option>  
</select>​
```

along with this jQuery snippet.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#btn').click(function () {
            $('select option[value="' + $('#input').val() + '"]').prop('selected', true);   
        });
    });​
</script>
```

Check out [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cyj5B/4/) for a working demo. Hope that helps! :)